# Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type (?)

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type` when I use the `.apply()` method and I'm not sure why. My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/7yYpe/).

When jsfiddle loads up, click next to the word test and hit the Enter key. The method that the error is occurring in is `this.addEvent`. I'm trying to have my object be the 'this' in the event's callback function.

Comment: Can you update the post, posting the code here, since the JSFiddle link is broken?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should use `.call` instead of `.apply`.

[`a.apply(obj, lst)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) is equivalent to `a(lst[0], lst[1], lst[2], ...)` when `lst` is an Array (or `arguments`) using `obj` as `this`.

[`a.call(obj, x, y, z, ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is equivalent to `a(x, y, z, ...)` using `obj` as `this`.

Since `e` is one of the arguments, not an array of arguments, you should use `.call`.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of *should or shouldn't*. It's perfectly possible to use `apply` with a single element array as it's second argument.

Answer (score 13):

`apply` expects an array object. You can also use `call` if you want to supply arguments directly. You can also convert arguments to an array using `apply`

```
func.apply(editorObject, [e]); //=> apply expects an array of arguments
func.call(editorObject, e);    //=> call receives arguments directly
```